# SSL certificate for LAN enviornment

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I have made a Silverlight 3.0 application, which communicates with an xml rpc server over https. The whole application will run in a LAN enviornment where server can be installed on different machines and client will on on same machine. I am using Self signed certificate which is generated against ip of server and I need to put in **Trusted Root Certification Authorties** on client machine. but if I want to communicate a second server then another certificate need to be installed on client machine against ip of that specific server, In short I need to install n certificates on client if I want to communicate n different servers, which is impossible for me, how can I do it with a single certificate over LAN enviornment. Certificates are generated against the ip or host name of server, is there any way to by pass the validation of SSL certificate? like

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MyCertHandler; 

static bool MyCertHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error) 
{ 
// Ignore errors 
return true; 
}
```

but the above code can't be used in Silverlight? any help?

Answer (score 1):

Dont use a Self Signed Certificate, and if you can to ignore authentication, then there is no good reason to use ssl.

For avoiding Self Signed Certs:
Set up a personal CA (*extremely easy to do with Microsoft's CA*). Then issue the server certificates from your own CA and give the CA's certificate to each of the servers as the trusted root. Then you end up with a setup like:

Cert Chains:

- A signed B
- A signed C
- A signed D
- A signed E

Deployment:

- Server B gets A and B
- Server C gets A and C
- Server D gets A and D
- Server E gets A and E

Then a client connecting into any of these servers can match the common name against the address it connected to, the valid date range against its own now time, and build a chain for validation to "CA Cert A" for every server.

(here is a random starting link for setting up your own CA server.)
[link text](http://www.petri.co.il/install_windows_server_2003_ca.htm)

If you try to use Selfsigned you will endup with

Cert Chains:

- B signed B
- C signed C
- D signed D
- E signed E

Cert Deployment

- Server B gets B, C, D, E
- Server C gets B, C, D, E
- Server D gets B, C, D, E
- Server E gets B, C, D, E